# Save gender as number or string on parse.com (to scale well)?

Tags: database, performance, parse-platform

I watched this very interesting talk about scaling parse applications:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wFQiQXQbto#t=29m33s

They state that a string data type is better for index optimization than a number, which is kinda counter intuitive for a query.
Shouldn't a comparison between strings always take longer than a number comparison?

That being said, I need to save 'gender', what gender to look for and query those as efficiently as possible.

Is it better to save it as a number

```
0 / 1 / 2
```

or as a string

```
male / female / both
```

to make future queries as efficient as possible?

Any advice highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this blog post](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/smart-indexing-at-parse/) on the parse.com website they rank strings above numbers in importance and so optimize there 'smart indexes' accordingly.

I would suggest going with there own recommendations for performance (or run your own tests if you don't want to take there word for it).

Comment: thanks! It just seems to counterintuitive. Would love if someone else could chip in with a (big) real world application out in the wild.

Comment: I don't know any details of there back end implementation but could imagine them using a hash table for constant time lookups on strings vs a sorted list for numerical indices requiring a non constant search time.